# Several assignment into one Select

Tags: c#, string, linq, entity-framework

In `Users` model, I have `DateTime dtContractStart` and `DateTime dtContractEnd`.

In `UserModel` model, I have `String dtContractStart` and `String dtContractEnd`.

To can perform a string cast with Linq query, I want to try something like that :

```
DateTime start;
DateTime end;

var users = DB.Users
    .Select(user => new UserModel
    {
        id = user.id,
        firstname = user.firstname,
        lastname = user.lastname,
        dtContractStart = "",
        dtContractEnd = "",
    }
        && start = user.dtContractStart
        && end = user.dtContractEnd
    )
    .ToList();

users.ForEach(user =>
    user.dtContractStart = start.toString() &&
    user.dtContractEnd = end.toString()
);
```

Is it possible? I don't find the good syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Set the variables with the last value from the query? Or vice versa, set all the created objects' start and end with a values from variables? Please clarify your intention.

Comment: I updated my question. I just want to achieve a string cast.

Comment: Then why not just doing `dtContractStart = user.dtContractStart.ToString()` in your `Select`?

Comment: I'm not getting the idea. Have you tried just setting `dtContractStart  = start` and `dtContractEnd = end`?

Comment: @KooKiz - Not all CLR methods can be used with Linq. ToString() seems to be one of them.

Comment: @GG I know those limitations exist for the `Where` clauses, but I didn't know there were the same limitations for the `Select` clause. For information, which Linq provider are you using? Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, ...?

Comment: @KooKiz - Entity Framework.

Comment: Why not just modify your `UserModel`? Consume datetimes, display strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Linq provider you're using doesn't accept the call to `ToString`, you can execute your query in two steps, using `AsEnumerable` to force the query execution:

```
var users = DB.Users
    .Where(...) // Whatever filtering clause inside your query
    .AsEnumerable() // Force the query execution, switching to Linq to Objects
    .Select(user => new UserModel
    {
        id = user.id,
        firstname = user.firstname,
        lastname = user.lastname,
        dtContractStart = user.dtContractStart.ToString(),
        dtContractEnd = user.dtContractEnd.ToString(),
    })
    .ToList();
```